# Conditional removing of items from a comma separated values within a columns of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, lambda

Say I have a data frame with 4 columns where two columns are comma-separated values of items and the other two columns just value.

```
    df.head()
    col1 col2 col3  col4     col5
    a.    34  67 34,44,55  41,54,67
    b.    75   105  75,90   85 105
```

And I need to remove the first item from `col4` if it is equal to value in `col2`. And so as, I wanna remove the last item in `col5` if it is equal to `col3`.

At the end the data frame should look like the following:

```
 df2.head()

    col1 col2 col3  col4     col5
    a.    34   67   44,55  41,54
    b.    75   105   90   85
```

I have tried using :

```
df.col4.map(lambda x: x.pop(0))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: In `col4` and `col5` you don't have lists but strings conducted from numbers and commas.

Comment: Yes, thanks and I have updated the post

Comment: I am sorry, But I cannot guess what is the exact type of  those values (except for the comma separated numbers which can only be strings). And type matters here - are 34, 67, etc. integers or strings?

Comment: Those are integers. Not strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your dataframe is defined as:

`df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[34, 67, "34,44,55", "41,54,67"], [75, 105, "75,90", "85,105"]], columns=["col2","col3","col4","col5"])`

You get the following dataframe:

```
   col2 col3  col4      col5
0   34  67    34,44,55  41,54,67
1   75  105   75,90     85,105
```

You can use `.apply()` with `axis=1` to apply a function across each dataframe row.

In this function, you first convert your string in `col4 (or col5)` into a list by splitting on `,`. Then, you can loop through items within the list and only keep those which are not equal to the integer in `col2 (or col3)`.

```
df["col4"] = df.apply(lambda row: ",".join([item for item in row["col4"].split(",") if int(item) != row["col2"]]), axis=1)
df["col5"] = df.apply(lambda row: ",".join([item for item in row["col5"].split(",") if int(item) != row["col3"]]), axis=1)
```

Here is the output you will get:

```
    col2    col3    col4    col5
0   34      67      44,55   41,54
1   75      105     90      85
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. however, the solution throws the following error:
`AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index 1')`

Comment: What if you replace ```row["col4"].split(",")``` by ```row["col4"].values.tolist()```?

Answer (score 1):

seems like col4 values are actually strs not lists - you should use `split(',')` on these (and perhaps cast it back to str after editing, depends what you plan to do later). Also `pop()` will return the element, so perhaps slice would be better: `lambda x: x.split(',')[1:]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but doing so `df.col4.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1:])` converts the column to `[]` which I do not  want.

Comment: you mean it is emptied or you don't want to have list as output?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have some spacing inconsisnenty issue, you may want to fix it. But this takes that into account for your need:

```
df['col4'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col4'] if row['col4'].split(',')[0].strip() != str(row['col2']) else ','.join(row['col4'].split(',')[1:]), axis=1)
df['col5'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col5'] if row['col5'].split(',')[-1].strip() != str(row['col3']) else ','.join(row['col5'].split(',')[:-1]), axis=1)
```

Comment: There is no space between the items within each columns of the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

split `col4` and `col5` to series of lists `s4`, `s5`. Next, use `np.where` to compare `col2` vs. `s4` and `col3` vs. `s5` and `join` the list to string as desired

```
s4 = df.col4.str.split(',\s*|\s+')
s5 = df.col5.str.split(',\s*|\s+') 
df['new_col4'] = np.where(df.col2.eq(s4.str[0].astype(int)), s4.str[1:].str.join(','), df.col2)
df['new_col5'] = np.where(df.col3.eq(s5.str[-1].astype(int)), s5.str[:-1].str.join(','), df.col3)

Out[358]:
  col1  col2  col3      col4      col5 new_col4 new_col5
0   a.    34    67  34,44,55  41,54,67    44,55    41,54
1   b.    75   105    75,90     85 105       90       85
```